# Logging best practice for classes

Tags: python, logging

I have implemented a logger in Python. Basically, the idea is to have a logger with multiple handlers. I do this with the following a yaml config

```
version: 1

formatters:
    simple:
        format: "%(name)s - %(lineno)d -  %(message)s"

    complex:
        format: "%(asctime)s - %(name)s | %(levelname)s | %(module)s : [%(filename)s: %(lineno)d] - %(message)s"

    json:
        class: utils.logger.JsonFormatter
        format: '%(asctime)s %(name)s %(levelname)s %(module)s %(filename)s: %(message)s'


handlers:
    console:
        class: logging.StreamHandler
        level: DEBUG
        formatter: json

    file:
        class: logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
        when: midnight
        backupCount: 5
        level: DEBUG
        formatter: complex
        filename : /tgs_workflow/logs/tgs_logs.log

    cloud:
        class: utils.logger.GoogleLogger
        formatter: json
        level: INFO

loggers:

    cloud:
        level: INFO
        handlers: [console,file,cloud]
        propagate: yes

    __main__:
        level: DEBUG
        handlers: [console,file,cloud]
        propagate: yes
```

In the yaml, I have created a class `GoogleLogger` and a class `JsonFormatter`, these are the only things outside the usual.

In order for this to work, anywhere I want to use my logger I (instantiate) do:

#### Instantiator [highlighted cause I refer back to it later]

```py
import logging
import logging.config
import yaml

with open('/tgs_workflow/logging.yaml','rt') as f:
        config=yaml.safe_load(f.read())
        f.close()
logging.config.dictConfig(config)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.info("This info")
```

Now there are two questions from here

Q1. Is it bad practice to have to instantiate this in each class/script I wish to use this? This also means there is lot of redundant code. (same code, multiple places)

Q2. I usually place this in `__main__` but what happens when I have a class that has no main but includes logging? I definitely know it's not a good idea to put this at the top of the file.

e.g. for Q2: This is a really bad example, but I am just trying to highlight how a class would need some logging

```
import logging

"""
>>>Insert Instantiator here <<<
"""

class Tools():
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def who_am_i(self, name, age):
        try:
            if (self.name == "Adam"):
                return True
                logging.info("This was Adam")
            else:
                return False
                logging.info("This was not Adam")
        except Exception:
            logging.error("There is an error")
```

The only way for me to use my logger is to include my **Instantiator** at the top of this class. That has to be incorrect or atleast not best practice? What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way is to either stick to a name and not use different loggers for every module/file, or use the hierarchy. If your tools class is imported by main than the `__main__` and `cloud` will already be configured and can be used. All you need to do is replace `>>>Insert Instantiator here <<<` with `logger = logging.getLogger('__main__')` and you are good to go. If you don't want to use directly on the main logger you can put a dot to make it a hierarchy. `logger = logging.getLogger('__main__.tools')`. Now this is a logger that will propagate its logs to the `__main__` logger but can have it's own level etc.

Comment: For future readers: I created a `setup_logging()` in my logger class. The logger is configured through yaml. And in my code I simply `setup_logging()` and then as @blues says `logger = logging.getLogger('__main__')` where `__main__` is the name of the logger I want to use.